# Is it possible to run 2 Kafka Streams JVMs with same application ID, but different topologies?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to run a Kafka Streams application which can have a change in topology and restart.
If I have 2 JVMs running and I stop one of the JVMs, the new JVM will have a different topology. Is this possible to run without problems? 
i.e., the application ID remains the same, but the topology might have changed.

Comment: The intermediate topics might be messed up if you keep the same application id but different topologies, but have you tried what you're asking yet?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this and seems to work. The only problem is for the first time, I noticed an exception being thrown. But after that, it runs as usual by rebalancing and reassigning the partitions. If by intermediate topics, you mean in our topology, we do not have any. If not, can you please help me understand what those intermediate topics are?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Internal+Data+Management

Answer (score 3):

No. All `KafkaStreams` instances that use the same `application.id` must run the exact some `Topology`.

Comment: Thank you, Matthias. I tried running different variations of our Kafka Streams application and it seems like, they do run. 

Here's my understanding. Please correct me if I've understood wrong: When two applications of different topologies run with the same application_id, the partition assignments/rebalancing happens between these two applications and neither application can read all of the data in the topics since the partitions are halved between each Kafka Streams application. I'm OK to have this kind of a scenario as we're planning to do a rolling restart of the JVMs.

Comment: That is correct -- however, note, that there is ***no*** guarantee that this really works... In general, it's expected that some exception is thrown for this case (maybe you are just lucky for your specific case that is works).

Comment: Thanks again, Matthias. It did throw an exception but it resumed running afterwards. So, I thought it to be the expected behavior.

Comment: If an exception is thrown the `StreamThread` should die and the `KafkaStream` client state should be `DEAD` -- however, the application/JVM would not crash because the exception is not thrown in the main thread... You should monitor the application state and/or register an uncaught exception handler. (Cf https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/write-streams.html#using-kstreams-within-your-application-code and https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/monitoring.html#runtime-status-information)

Comment: Yes, we do have an uncaught exception handler and are monitoring it. Thanks again, Matthias.